# How to add a gap to a UISearchController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchcontroller, navigationitem

I've added a search controller using the storyboard and added in the search controller programmatically. I'm having a bit of trouble centering the search bar vertically so that it's not touching the top navigation bar (see photo). How I added the search bar code is posted below.

Any help is appreciated.

`self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController;
self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = NO;`

Comment: please add a screenshot of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a vertical constraint to your search bar as I've done in this image:

[image]

You can set the vertical constraint by clicking the tie-fighter like icon at the bottom of XCode.  Set your constraint to 8 for example then click the I-bar followed by add 1 constraint:

[image]